# QTabBar.setTabButton() inside subclass crashes the Application

Tags: pyside

In the following Python snippet, The application is crashed when I run it. I tested it on Mac OS X, Windows and Ubuntu:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class TabbedWindow(QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TabbedWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(u"Tabs Test")
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.addTab(QTextEdit(), "Tab 1")
        self.addTab(QCalendarWidget(), "Tab 2")

        self.setTabsClosable(True)

        tabBar = self.tabBar()
        menuButton = QPushButton('')
        menuButton.resize(0,0)
        tabBar.setTabButton(1, QTabBar.RightSide, menuButton)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    tabs = TabbedWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(tabs)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I remove this line `tabBar.setTabButton(1, QTabBar.RightSide, menuButton)` it works!

Also, If I moved this line to `main` function: it works too! I mean when I added this to main function:

```
tabBar = tabs.tabBar()
menuButton = QPushButton('')
menuButton.resize(0,0)
tabBar.setTabButton(1, QTabBar.RightSide, menuButton)
```

What I want to do is hiding Close Button on some tabs.

Is there any workaround to perform this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer to make it work!

You have to declare the button as a member of the class.

```
self.menuButton = QPushButton('')
```

instead of

```
menuButton = QPushButton('')
```

I hope someone will find this solution is useful.